# gfortran open statement does not support blocksize?

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

I am new to FORTRAN and try to re-compile some `.F90` codes in a WIN7 64-bit system with gfortan 4.5.2. The source code has been successfully compiled using LAHEY compiler, which I do not have access... My question is related to the `blocksize` option in the `open` statement, which is:

```
open (unit=RANUNT, file=trim(DAFile_Name), status='old',&
    action='readwrite', recl=LENREC, access='direct',&         
    form='UNformatted', blocksize=LENREC, iostat=It_is_OK)
```

The error message I got is

```
    form='UNformatted', blocksize=LENREC, iostat=It_is_OK) 
                       1
Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)
```

So my question: Is this `blocksize` option not supported in gfortran? What potential problems I could run into by removing it?

Thanks!

#### Update

The program works fine in Windows XP compatibility mode. However, it complained in Windows 7 mode. The error I got in Windows 7 are:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  6f61143e
#1  6f68ec2f
#2  00401261
```

Answer (score 1):

"blocksize" keyword of an `open` statement is not standard Fortran.  You should have no problems by omitting it.  It is an instruction to the OS to write to the output device in groups of bytes. Modern hardware (are you writing to a disk?) has builtin sophisticated buffering.

Comment: Thanks. The problem I am having is after omitting it, the compiled .exe file got me `has stopped working` error (though it generates output files). In addition, I have changed another lahey expression `inquire (file=ErrorFile, flen=It_is_OK)` to `inquire (file=ErrorFile, size=It_is_OK)`

Comment: Do you test "It_is_OK" immediately after this open statement?  If it is zero, then the open was successful.   If the open was successful, then the problem with your program is likely elsewhere.   If it is non-zero, then you should figure out what that error value means.  If the program wrote to this file, then the open must have worked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will check `It_is_OK`. But may I know how to check ` test "It_is_OK" immediately after this open statement`. Sorry for the rookie question.

Comment: `write (*, *) "It_is_OK after open:", It_is_OK` will write to the terminal.  Use a different output unit number if necessary.

Comment: I checked It_is_Ok and it is 0... So based on your experience, the problem happened somewhere else?

Comment: `iostat = 0` means success, so the open statement ran without error.  If you are getting an error message from the program, find where that message is written and the conditions that might cause output of the message.  If the program doesn't distinguish between multiple conditions that cause output of its error message, add code to do so so that you know which condition is activating the error message.  Then you will know what you need to understand & fix.

Comment: I think, there is a misunderstanding. `INQUIRE` checks for properties of a file (in your case `ErrorFile`) and does _NOT_ open it. The variable `It_is_OK` should only report the length of this file and I would guess, that a value of `0` could be interpreted as there are no errors.

Comment: This is why I suggested checking `It_is_OK` immediately after the `open` statement, where is it is used with `iostat` -- to avoid the conflicting usage of this variable in the `inquire` statement.

Comment: A hexadecimal backtrace doesn't tell us much.  With gfortran, try the compiler options: `-fcheck=all  -fbacktrace`.

Comment: I added the above options and recompiled the program. If I ran under "admin privileges", everything is fine. However, if I ran as a regular user, it reports some boundary errors. I am not sure why this "admin privileges" could cause so much differences?

Comment: What kind of boundary errors?  Out of memory?  Perhaps the program doesn't have enough memory when run as a regular user?  Try increasing the memory available to the process.